# Java applet needs permission but doesn't ask for it!

Tags: macos, permissions, java

I'm trying to connect a VPN connection (on Mac OS X 10.6.6) through a Check point java applet. The first time it ran I chose NOT to give it access to my files and such and now every time I try to lunch the applet it tells me too

> "Please confirm the use of this Java applet and then refresh or reopen the window."

But I don't know how to confirm it nor delete the applet.

How can I change the permissions afterwards and where can I find java applets installed on my computer?

Update: This turns out to be a problem in Firefox. Cleared cookies, Java cache and certificate in Safari and it seems to work.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to superuser, as it's an end-user support question not software development...

Comment: I don't really know what that means but migrate away! ...or in case I have to do it, how do I?

Comment: @Karl, you wouldn't be able to migrate it on your own - I've flagged it for a moderator (or if 5 high-rep users vote on it it can be triggered that way too)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120628052518/http://pscode.org/test/docload/) is a page I wrote about defensive loading of trusted applets.  The [sandbox.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120831211126/http://pscode.org/test/docload/sandbox.html) linked from that page has some tips intended for the end user who initially refuses trust to an applet but then reconsiders.  I am not sure if it will work for Mac:

> Once a decision has been made to either Run or Cancel the trusted code, modern browsers (e.g. IE6, FF3) tend to remember that first decision through page refreshes (typically F-5) and 'force reload' page refresh (Ctrl F-5).
>
> To get a second prompt of the security dialog, it is usually necessary to do either of:
>
> - Stop that browser session/instance, then restart the browser.
> - Clear the classes from cache using the Java Console (type 'x' when the console has focus), then reload the page.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I at least learned something new. I tried clearing the session and the java cache but it still doesn't ask me. This is very strange.

Comment: @Andrew: Your page contains a working example, but no indication on how to do this. Could you add this, or explain a bit?